# Vue.js UI does not update the state on window reload

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following code structure (simplified):

```
<template v-for="tile of layer.data">
    <VueDragResize :x="calculatePositionX(tile)">
        <h2 :style="{'font-size':calculateFontSize(tile) + 'px'}">Test</h2>
    </VueDragResize>
</template>
```

The `:x="calculatePositionX(tile)` and `:style="{'font-size':calculateFontSize(tile) + 'px'}"` values are dynamic. I want to change these values on window resize.

To achieve this I do this: (too keep it simple I want to show you only the `calculatePositionX`  example).

```
mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
},
beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},
methods: {
    onResize(event) {
      this.calculatePositionX(null);
    },
    calculatePositionX(tile) {
        if (!tile) {
            tile = this.cachedTile;
        }
        
        this.cachedTile = tile;
        let x = tile.boxPositionX;
        let parentWidth = tile.boxPositionParentWidth;
        let currentParentWidth = this.$refs.builderLayer.clientWidth;
        
        if (parentWidth == currentParentWidth) {
            return x;
        }
        console.log(currentParentWidth * x / parentWidth); // Returns different result as the initial, but the state is not updating
        return currentParentWidth * x / parentWidth;        
    },
}
data() {
  return {
    cachedTile: Object,
  }
},
```

The `console.log(currentParentWidth * x / parentWidth);` returns a different result as the initial, but the state is not updating on the UI.

What can be the issue here? I also tried to save the new value as variable into the store and return the store result. Without success.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You defined `calculatePositionX` on the Vue instance itself.

Move it inside `methods` and it will work.

---

Side note: you might want to replace `cachedTile: Object` with `cachedTile: {}` in `data`.

Comment: Sorry, it was just a copy paste error for this posts. The `calculatePositionX()` is inside the methods, but its not working :/

Comment: @asored, in that case, you might want to create a *runnable* [mcve], so the bug can be inspected. The code you posted so far is not sufficient to repro the bug, which makes your question unanswerable. If you need a node-like online editor, use codesandbox.io or similar.

Answer (score 0):

In the OP code, you call `calculatePositionX` on resize, but ignore the return. The template won't know to update on the resize, but it will if dependent data changes.

Rather than returning the result of the resize calculation, have your  `calculatePositionX` method change the state, then, let vue reactive getters do their job in the template. Refer to `x` in data (which is set by the slightly modified `calculatePositionX`)

```
<template v-for="tile of layer.data">
    <VueDragResize :x="x">
        <h2 :style="style(tile)">Test</h2>
    </VueDragResize>
</template>  


mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onResize);
    this.onResize();
},
beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.onResize)
},
methods: {
    onResize(event) {
      this.calculatePositionX(null);
    },
    calculatePositionX(tile) {
        if (!tile) {
            tile = this.cachedTile;
        }
        
        this.cachedTile = tile;
        let x = tile.boxPositionX;
        let parentWidth = tile.boxPositionParentWidth;
        let currentParentWidth = this.$refs.builderLayer.clientWidth;
        
        if (parentWidth == currentParentWidth) {
            this.x = x;
            return;
        }
        console.log(currentParentWidth * x / parentWidth); 
        this.x = currentParentWidth * x / parentWidth;        
    },
    style(tile) {
      return {'font-size':calculateFontSize(tile) + 'px'}
    }
}
data() {
  return {
    x: 0, // will get initialized in mounted
    cachedTile: Object,
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi danh! Thanks, but the problem here is that I have no reference to the `tile` data from the `v-for` on mounted. The param from `this.calculatePositionX(null);` will always be null, so there also will be no `this.cachedTile` data. How could we handle this in the vue architecture?

Comment: @asored, layer.data, is presumably in data or a prop.  Why don't you have access to it?

Comment: I have access to `layer.data`, that's correct. But in this case I need access to the specific single tile while looping the array to calculate the position. Therefore I passed the single tile as param to the function inside the for loop: `calculatePositionX(tile)` Or I am wrong?

Comment: You can loop layer.data in code, just as you do in the template, but maybe I'm beginning to see the issue: I think you might be missing dimensionality in the "x" data.  Each tile in layer data needs an x computed?  If so, you need an array of x values just as long.  Or you might augment each tile object with an x, and keep that data with the object it pertains to